# How to extract first items from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a rather large list of tuples which contains:

```
[('and', 44023), ('cx', 37711), ('is', 36777), ...]
```

I just want to extract the first string, so the output for the above list would be:

```
and
cx
is
```

How do I code this (with extensibilty built in to some degree)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to provide an alternative way to the solution by Matthew.

```
tuples = [('and', 44023), ('cx', 37711), ('is', 36777) .... ]
strings, numbers = zip(*tuples)
```

In case you at some point decide you want both parts of the tuple in separate sequences (avoids two list comprehensions).

Comment: if your list is really quite large, note that this doubles your memory requirements.

Answer (score 15):

```
[tup[0] for tup in mylist]
```

This uses a list comprehension.  You could also use parentheses instead of the outer brackets to make it a generator comprehension, so evaluation would be lazy.

Comment: +1 for the note about generator comprehension. Didn't know it worked that way.

Comment: -1 for generator usage. This breaks nearly half of the Zen of Python:  python -c 'import this'

Comment: @bukzor I believe adding the outer parentheses would **explicitly** make it a generator (no one did it behind your back).

Comment: What does using a generator instead of a list comprehension have anything to do with being explicit or implicit?

Comment: @orangeoctopus My comment was in reference to bukzor's comment before it was edited.  I think the above solution is clear and pythonic.

Comment: @awesomeo My comment was in reference to his, too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the exact output

```
and
cx
is
```

Then use a list comprehension in combination with the strings `join` method to join the newline chararcter like so

```
yourList = [('and', 44023), ('cx', 37711), ('is', 36777)]
print '\n'.join([tup[0] for tup in yourList])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack your tuples in a for loop, like so:

```
for word, count in mytuple:
    print "%r is used %i times!" % (word, count)
```

You can see this used extensively in the Python docs:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-technique